# Single word for a contributing part of a project

Tags: single-word-requests

I am working on a project producing guidance - known as 'the guidance project'.

Within that project are individual pieces of work where guidance is produced on different subjects. These are unconnected documents, ie they stand alone and are not chapters or parts of a whole.

There is no foreseeable end to the guidance project, guidance will continue to be produced as and when it is needed. In effect, each document is a 'mini project'. I am looking for a word which encompasses all the work involved in the production of each document. Is there a single word which avoids repeating the word 'project'?

**Edit**
To clarify, I am looking for a term for the 'work in progress' aspect of the production of the guidance (consultation, draft, edit, sign-off) and not the finished product.

Comment: a "module" or "training module" could fit see for example  http://www.ifrs.org/IFRS-for-SMEs/Pages/Training-Modules.aspx

Comment: @P.O. 'Module' is on the right lines, thanks, but I will edit the post to clarify.

Comment: Perhaps "resources" or "solutions"?

Comment: Either your projects are not related at all and then they're all called projects (project x, y, z) or if they have some connection between them but still can be envisioned as fitting a purpose on their own:  they're called sub-projects (in the project management field).  I don't know any other word. http://project-management-knowledge.com/definitions/s/subproject/

Comment: Another common word would be "component".

Answer (score 1):

It is a ***task***.

businessdictionary.com:

> ***[task](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/task.html)***
>
> The smallest identifiable and essential piece of a job that serves as
>   a unit of work, and as a means of differentiating between the various
>   components of a project.

Comment: Thanks, I had considered 'task' but I'm really looking for a word for a collection of tasks. As indicated in my edit, each piece of work is a collection of several different tasks.

Comment: A _task_ can consist of _[subtasks](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/subtask)_, if that helps.